# Botão gravar com opção

Tags: php, html

Tenho um botão guardar no html que serve para guardar os dados de um formulario na BD mas depois de guardar quero que ele abra uma janela a perguntar:"Novo registo?"com duas opções
com sim e não.
Se for sim abre a pagina x se for não abre a pagina y

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador VALUES(0,'".$Tecnico."','".$Seguranca."','".$Nome1."','".$Funcao1."','".$Nome2."','".$Funcao2."','".$Nome3."','".$Funcao3."','".$Nome4."')" ;      



mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
//mysql_query($sqlinsert2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dessa forma poderá ajudar, só não estará explicitamente as opções "sim" e "não".
O código a seguir está funcionando para abrir as respectivas páginas, de acordo com a opção escolhida:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador VALUES(0,'".$Tecnico."','".$Seguranca."','".$Nome1."','".$Funcao1."','".$Nome2."','".$Funcao2."','".$Nome3."','".$Funcao3."','".$Nome4."')" 
          or die(mysql_error());

if ($insert)
{
    echo "<script>var r = confirm('Novo Registro?');" .
    "if (r == true) {window.open('page-x.html');}" .
    "else {window.open('page-y.html');}</script>";
}
```

Comment: Sim, O Sim abre uma pagina html x e o não abre uma pagina html y

Comment: So uma duvida para abrir a pagina no mesmo separador? Faz a pagina popup com a pergunta e depois abre na pagina onde estava